# UFT/QTP Compatibility with IE10 and Oracle Forms

Tags: forms, oracle, internet-explorer, qtp, quirks-mode

I'd like to know whether the UFT/QTP is compatibale with the applications which is opening in IE10 browser under "IE5 Quirks" document mode? Also the UFT/QTP compatibility with Oracle Forms applications?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regarding *IE5 Quirks* mode, yes, QTP is compatible with it.